# How the file renaming thing happens (backend) in cloud services?

Tags: google-drive-api, cloud, dropbox-api

Does anybody has idea how cloud platforms like dropbox, googledrive do manage file renaming conflicts?
Because when a file is renamed in the cloud drive in our local machine/cloud drive previous file will also sync along with the new file. which is

cloud drive:          cloud folder in local machine:
test.txt                test.txt

when i rename test.txt in cloud drive it will be renamed and it will sync to the local machine. at the same time test.txt will sync from local machine to the cloud drive as new file.

How to avoid creating this duplicate file while renaming?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Drive, there is no such thing as a "naming conflict". Files are identified by their unique ID, thus having multiple files with the same name is perfectly fine.